# Solving PDE $u_{t} = (1-s)\mu u_{s} + (s-1)\alpha u$ with method of characteristics.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

I am trying to solve the following PDE using the method of characteristics,

$$u_{t} = (1-s)\mu u_{s} + (s-1)\alpha u,$$
$$u(s,0) = s^i$$

We can reduce the PDE to the following set of ODEs along the characteristic curves,

$$\frac{dt}{1} = \frac{-ds}{\mu(1-s)} = \frac {du}{(s-1)\alpha u}.$$

On solving two ODEs we get,

$$t\mu - \ln|1-s| = A,$$
$$(s-1) \alpha t - \ln|u| = B .$$

So, the general solution is,

$$f(t\mu - \ln|1-s|, (s-1) \alpha t - \ln|u|) = 0.$$

I also know that after plugging in the initial condition we get
$-\ln (s^{i}) = B$, $-\ln(1-s) = A$ which gets us,

$$-\ln[(1-e^{-A})^{i}] = B .$$

How do I get a specific solution from here?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a first-order linear PDE with variable coefficients. The characteristic families are
$$
\mu t - \ln (1-s) = A, \qquad\text{or}\qquad (1-s)e^{-\mu t} = e^{-A} = A'
$$
$$
\tfrac\alpha\mu s - \ln u = B, \qquad\text{or}\qquad u\, e^{-\alpha s/\mu} = e^{-B} = B'
$$
where composition with the exponential has been used twice (2nd integration in OP is incorrect).
Introducing an explicit dependence $B' = F(A')$ yields the general solution
$$
u = e^{\alpha s/\mu} F\big((1-s)e^{-\mu t}\big) \, ,
$$
where $F$ is an arbitrary function.
At $t=0$, we have
$u = e^{\alpha s/\mu} F(1-s)$ and $u = s^i$.
Setting $r = 1-s$, we find $F(r) = e^{\alpha (r-1)/\mu} (1-r)^i$ by using the boundary condition. Thus,
$$
u(s,t) = e^{\alpha (1-s)(e^{-\mu t}-1)/\mu} \big(1-(1-s)e^{-\mu t}\big)^i .
$$
We can compute the partial derivatives to verify the solution (and it works!).